# CalledFromWrongThreadException: Android ContentObserver and Activity interface

Tags: android, view, sms, listactivity, contentobserver

I have a `ListActivity` with a SMS `ContentObserver`. The `ListView` displays
SMS sent/received.
Whenever there is change in the SMS database (sent/received), the observer
calls a function within the `Activity` which updates the `ListView`.

This works ok in FROYO. But in ICS I get the following

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Please let me know what could be the issue.

The following is the top level code.

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity implements OnInitListener{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        MyList.this.getContentResolver()
            .unregisterContentObserver(smsObserver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MyList.this.getContentResolver()
            .unregisterContentObserver(smsObserver); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.MyList );

        registerSmsEventObserver();
        updateList();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerSmsEventObserver();
    }

    updateList() {
        //fill up the listview
    }

    private void registerSmsEventObserver() {      
        if (smsObserver != null)
            return; 

        smsObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {             
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {   
                updateList();
            }
        };
        MyList.this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsObserver);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tells you that you can't touch the listview from within the observer. Please send also the function called by the observer (`updateList()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One does not simply call `updateList();` from another thread, which is ContentObserver thread. Instead, you'd better wrap it with `runOnUiThread();` like

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateList();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `ContentObserver` passing

```
new Handler()
```

This will make the `onChange` running on the looper of the main thread since you are creating the observer in the main thread.